# Несколько вопросов по нейросети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Работаю над нейросетью. и есть несколько вопросов.

1. почему тестовые данные имеют разные размеры.(Х в 2 раза больше Y)
2. как добавить результаты работы в процентах.
3. почему TestY полностью совпадает с исходными данными, а TestX не возвращает нормализованные данные.
4. и как вообще посмотреть прогнозируемый результат.

в файле.csv один столбец на 1400 строк с какой_то последовательностью( уже точно и не скажу)

Вот код.

```
import numpy
from pandas import read_csv
import math
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)
# load the dataset
dataframe = read_csv('test3.csv', usecols=[0], engine='python')
dataset = dataframe.values
dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.75)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]
# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 1
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)
# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))
# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=20, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)
# invert predictions
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict)
trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPredict)
testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])
# calculate root mean squared error
trainScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(trainY[0], trainPredict[:,0]))
print('Train Score: %.2f RMSE' % (trainScore))
testScore = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(testY[0], testPredict[:,0]))
print('Test Score: %.2f RMSE' % (testScore))
#
print(testX)
print(testY.T)
```

вот результат.

```
Epoch 10/20
- 52s - loss: 0.1695
Epoch 11/20
- 52s - loss: 0.1697
Epoch 12/20
- 52s - loss: 0.1694
Epoch 13/20
- 52s - loss: 0.1694
Epoch 14/20
- 52s - loss: 0.1695
Epoch 15/20
- 52s - loss: 0.1696
Epoch 16/20
- 52s - loss: 0.1696
Epoch 17/20
- 52s - loss: 0.1691
Epoch 18/20
- 52s - loss: 0.1694
Epoch 19/20
- 52s - loss: 0.1694
Epoch 20/20
- 52s - loss: 0.1693
Train Score: 0.82 RMSE
Test Score: 0.79 RMSE

TestX 735 lines.
TestY 368 lines.
```